# Changing background-color when div fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change `background-color` when a `div` fade-in but the below code did not worked.

Instead it only `fadeOut` and nothing shows when I tried to `click` to `fadeIn.`

```
$('#divbutton').toggle(function(){
        $('#divbutton').text('Show');
        $('#message').fadeOut('1000');

   } , 
   function(){
       $('#divbutton').text('Hide');
       $('#message').$this.css('background-color', 'red').fadeIn('1000');

   }
);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$('#message').$this`?

Comment: please indent properly your code

Comment: Probably want to remove `$this`. `$(this)` would refer to the `#divbutton` I believe. Are you not getting a syntax error in the console? You must be./

Comment: Remove the this. and try this $('#message').css();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax to the following line is incorrect. change:

$('#message').$this.css('background-color', 'red').fadeIn('1000');

to:

$('#message').css('background-color', 'red').fadeIn('1000');